# removeItem localStorage does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to remove a item in an array but it doesn't get removed. I have the id of the item but I can't use it. Can you show me how I can use the id of item in `tasks` array?

```
function appendTaskToList(val, task_id) {
    $('#list').append($("<li>  <a href='#' class='done-btn'>Done</a>" +
        " " + val + " <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancel-btn'>Delete</a></li>")
    .data("task", task_id));
}

if (localStorage['tasks']) {

    var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage['tasks']);
    for(var i=0;i<tasks.length;i++) {
        appendTaskToList(tasks[i], i);
    }

}else {

    var tasks = [];
}

var addTask = function(){
    var val = $('#name').val();
    tasks.push(val);
    var task_id = tasks.indexOf(val);
    localStorage["tasks"] = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    appendTaskToList(val, task_id);
    $('#name').val("").focus();
};

$('#add-btn').click(addTask);


$('#name').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addTask();
    }

});

$(document).delegate('.done-btn', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('done');
    return false;
});
```

I'm stuck here:

```
$(document).delegate('.cancel-btn', 'click', function(e) {
    var task_elem = $(e.target).closest("li");

    console.log(task_elem.data());
    var taks_id = task_elem.data();
    $(this).parent('li').remove();

    localStorage.removeItem(tasks[taks_id]);



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one localStorage property which is `"tasks"`.

The value of this property is the json you stringify.

In the line `localStorage.removeItem(tasks[taks_id]);` the value of `tasks[taks_id]` is not `"tasks"`.

Therefore you are looking to delete something in localStorage that doesn't even exist

What you need to do is remove the item from your `tasks` javascript array and then save the modified array to localStorage again.

Assuming `task_id` is the index in array:

```
//remove from array
tasks.splice(task_id,1);
//store again
localStorage.setItem('tasks',JSON.stringify(tasks));
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: task_id is not defined    ı have this error when ı click the delete button

Comment: tasks.splice(task_elem.data(),1);
         localStorage.setItem('tasks',JSON.stringify(tasks));                             ı use this code and boom! its work :) thank you bro